# Change the maximum size of a (possibly maximized) window?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, window

Is there a way to change the maximum size of a *possibly maximized* window, **without** changing the maximization state of the window? (I'm referring to[`MINMAXINFO.ptMaxSize` and `MINMAXINFO.ptMaxTrackSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632605.aspx) here.)

Or, in other words: How do I tell the system to send my window a `WM_GETMINMAX` and refresh its state as necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think I found a solution:

```
SetWindowPos(
    hWnd, NULL, rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height,
    SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Comment: Or, as you know the new limit, just set it explicitly